# simplifying radicals and fractional numbers

Tags: radicals

> $$\frac{a}{a-\sqrt{a^2-16}}$$ is the expression.
>   I am not sure if i answered it right but please help me do this.

Comment: Is $$\frac{a}{a-\sqrt{a^2-16}}$$ the correct interpretation of the expression?

Comment: @DanielFischer yes.

Comment: Where is the equation?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee \frac{a}{a-\sqrt{a^2-16}}

Comment: @ikaidubidu, the only thing we can do is rationalize the denominator $$\frac a{a-\sqrt{a^2-16}}=\frac{a(a+\sqrt{a^2-16})}{a^2-(a^2-16)}=\cdots$$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have is an expression, but not an equation. We can indeed *simplify* the expression.

We can multiply by the *conjugate* of the denominator, to obtain a *difference of squares.*, e.g. $$\begin{align}\frac{a}{a-\sqrt{a^2-16}} & = \frac{a(a + \sqrt{a^2 - 16)}}{(a - \sqrt {a^2 - 16})(a + \sqrt{a^2 - 16})} \\ \\ & = \frac{a(a + \sqrt{a^2 - 16)}}{a^2 - (a^2 - 16)}\\ \\
& = \frac{{a(a + \sqrt{a^2 - 16)}}}{ 16}\end{align}$$

**Added:** What we've accomplished is called "rationalizing the denominator", which simply means getting the "radical" out of the denominator.

Comment: @amWy: always trying to teach! :-) +1